# in java, does anonymous class will occupy PermGeneration or MetaGeneration?

Tags: java

Java can create anonymous class inherent interface/class as following:

```
new Thread(new run(){
 // code to run
});
```

will create anonymous class and it's instance.

My question is , does dynamic generated class and it's instance(object) will occupy heap space and perm space ？

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous class will just be with the regular classes and is compiled just once. It's not a special case. Just check the documentation for your relevant Java version.

Note that Java 8 no longer has permspace. What Java version is this about?

Comment: java 8. you means these class will occupy meatspace ?

Comment: Yeah it will be in the MetaSpace.